# Bootstrap - number of columns in the list on the sidebar

Tags: bootstrap-4

On extra small size I want to have three columns of a list above the 'main' div. On bigger size screens I need ONE column on the left of the 'main' div.

It works fine on extra-small size but on bigger screens it affects 'sidebar div' in the way its on the top of 'main', like it had class assigned "col-xs-4 col-sm-12". How can I change it?

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2" id="sidebar">
        <ul class="row">
             <li "col-xs-4 col-sm-12"> 1</li>
             <li "col-xs-4 col-sm-12"> 2 </li>
             <li "col-xs-4 col-sm-12"> 3</li>
             <li "col-xs-4 col-sm-12"> 4</li>
             <li "col-xs-4 col-sm-12"> 5</li>
        </ul>
    <div class="col-sm-10" id="main">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm no bootstrap expert, but why is your ul class row?  Why are your list items col-sm-12 and you didn't specify class there?  Seems like everything would be a lot better off if you didn't have that

Comment: I think you need to clarify the question

Comment: On extra small size I want to have three columns of a list above the 'main' div. On bigger size screens I need  ONE column on the  left of the 'main' div. Hope it makes sense.